# Adding a row to a dataset C#

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I have a code like this:

```
DataRow[] drMyRow = mydataset.Tables[0].Select("ColumnName=" + smth );
                                if (drMyRow .Length == 0)
                                {
                                    DataRow dr = mydataset.Tables[0].NewRow();
                                    dr["ColumnName"] = smth ;
                                    mydataset.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
                                }
drMyRow = mydataset.Tables[0].Select("ColumnName=" + smth );
```

In debug mode I see new added row using dataset visualizer. But when I run this line again;

```
drMyRow = mydataset.Tables[0].Select("ColumnName=" + smth );
```

drMyRow.Length shows 0 again. I tried getchanges() or acceptchanges() but not working. Is there a solution, what is my mistake ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this behavior. Is this all of your code around this problem?

Comment: I have some calculations between two "select" commands, but they are not effecting "mydataset". And its not a string problem.